# problems with ruby on rails 3 on windows 7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows-7, scaffolding

I have run into an error while running rails 3 on win7 64 bit and mysql 5.1.

It has to do with mysql2. Any assistance would be helpful.

```
C:\mobile_projects>rails new test2 -d mysql
      create  
      create  README
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/mailers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/server.log
      create  log/production.log
      create  log/development.log
      create  log/test.log
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
          create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  public/images
      create  public/images/rails.png
      create  public/stylesheets
      create  public/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  public/javascripts
      create  public/javascripts/application.js
      create  public/javascripts/controls.js
      create  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
      create  public/javascripts/effects.js
      create  public/javascripts/prototype.js
      create  public/javascripts/rails.js
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/functional
      create  test/integration
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/unit
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/sessions
      create  tmp/sockets
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/pids
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep

C:\mobile_projects>cd test2

C:\mobile_projects\test2>rails generate scaffold testtbl desc:string legsnumber:string
[31mCould not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.[0m

C:\mobile_projects\test2>
```

Comment: Do you have mysql in your gemfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this..i simply went into the gemfile and changed the mysql2 references to mysql and things worked fine...

Answer (score 3):

The last line in the output you provided is clearly indicating what you're missing. It is mentioning that the gem `mysql2` is not installed, and that you should run `bundle install` to install them.

You didn't mention how you obtained that version of Ruby, but I will assume you installed [Rubyinstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org) packages.

Now, mysql2 gem lacks binaries for Windows at this time (it is something I'm working on right now).

I have two recommendations: either you use sqlite3 (which should work out of the box with RubyInstaller or specially [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org) package.

Or you install and compile mysql2 gem following similar instructions to the ones posted in [RubyInstaller wiki](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Tutorials) about installing and compiling MySQL adapter.

Hope all this helps or makes sense.

Comment: i installed ruby using instantrhodes..i actually planned to use sql server but i cant seem to get it working with rails 3..installing myql2 gem gives an error too...i'll try your suggestion from the rubyinstaller wiki..thanks